# Intellij maven install with lowest checksum value

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-install-plugin

I use intellij 2019.3.1 and when I run mvn clean install I want to get latest package version.My problem is I have a maven package which is same version but has different checksum value.When I check I see all these checksum versions downloaded but intellij use the lowest one.

```
MyPackage 1.0.0 SNAPHSOT -->mypackage checksum value 2020040201
MyPackage 1.0.0 SNAPHSOT -->mypackage checksum value 2020040202
```

in my pom only I use MyPackage 1.0.0 SNAPHSOT.And intellij uses the lowest checksum value?How can I handle this issue

Comment: What is `3.1` at the beginning of your post? Can elaborate more you mean cause I don't understand what you mean by `checksum` cause what you are showing is a time marker which is the usual way in case of SNAPSHOT's ?

Comment: I write wrong and fix it intellij 2019.3.1 version.And I upload my jar file with same version name to my repository.And My artifact repository(artifactory) upload like this myfile-1.0.0-20200224.021923-1.This all same version 1.0.0 but different checksum 20200224.021923-1

Comment: This is not a checksum it's just a time marker...which is the usual SNAPSHOT's will be handled by repository managers ...

Comment: myproblem is intellij take the lowest one not highest snapshot with this timemaker

Comment: When have you created/deployed the latest SNAPSHOT? You can force to use the most recent on command line via `mvn -U ..` or you can configure the behaviour in your `settings.xml` https://maven.apache.org/settings.html via the `updatePolicy` which means by default only each 24 hours will be checked...

Comment: it downloaded latest one,and I see it in maven packages. and I use -U parameter to.My problem is intellij choose lowest dependency